# Persist attributes from a base layer to a grid layer

Tags: fields-attributes, vector-grid, metadata

I currently have a shapefile of municipalities and towns as the base layer which contains attributes such as municipal name and baranggay name (town). I would want to create a hexagonal grid on top of such layer but persisting the attributes of the base layer to the grid. Meaning that the grid shapes would also contain the municipal and baranggay it belongs to.

Is this possible to do this in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think you need to use [Join attributes by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location).